# Mesos & Kafka: how to configure and run multiple kafka brokers on mesos cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka, mesos, marathon

I know that native integration with Mesos API is planned for Kafka 0.9 release. Meanwhile it is would be great to run and scale Kafka brokers using Marathon. Does anybody have the experience of doing it already?

Comment: I'm really curious how did you solve the problem? I have a similar situation, I would like to run multiple Kafka brokers on Mesos with Marathon. I'm thinking what to use as a broker id. I know that some people are using IP based id, but i read that this approach can cause some issues when migrating the broker to a different machine. Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

Some certainly do. See the discussion on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1207, especially the last comment from Joe Stein. If you're in the NYC area this week, you could also check out http://www.meetup.com/Apache-Mesos-NYC-Meetup/events/219073804/?a=me1_grp&rv=me1&_af_eid=219073804&_af=event